# Volume of tent with a circular base and stretched over a semicircular rod

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

A tent consists of canvas stretched from a circular base
of radius "a" to a vertical semicircular rod fastened to the
base at the ends of a diameter. Find the volume of this
tent.

I was trying:

$$dV = \pi \frac{a^2}{h^2}x^2dx$$
$$V = \int_0^h \pi \frac{a^2}{h^2}x^2dx = \frac{1}{3}\pi a^2*h $$

which is not the correct answer

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to find the volume of a cone with height $h$ and radius $r$?

Comment: @DavidRaveh right I thought maybe the tent has the same volume as the cone but it not

Comment: I was thinking about the invariant which is the rod I am planning to take pieces of tent as hypotenuse of the rod

Comment: Does it make a difference if the rod is circular as opposed to ‘semicircular’?

Comment: @Ace if semicircular you have a flat surface on the right, but we should try the book answer is $4a^3/3$

Comment: I think the question is trying to suggest a certain shape to a cross-section of the tent, but it's not very clear what that shape should be...

Comment: Several other shapes are possible,  e.g., surfaces of constant mean curvature, Coon's surface..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the base circle be $x^2+y^2 =a^2$ and the semicircular rod $x^2+z^2=a^2$. Then, the volume of the tent is 4-times that of the first octant, which can be viewed as stack of right isosceles triangular plates alone the $x$ direction. So, the tent volume is integrated as
$$V =4\int_0^a \frac12 y^2(x)dx
= 4\int_0^a \frac12 (a^2-x^2)\ dx=\frac43a^3
$$

[image]

Comment: also help me visualize the first octant

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts - See the 1st octant graph

Comment: very intuitive explanation you are a great teacher

Comment: Hi @Quanto, may I ask what you used to draw the picture?

Comment: @Quanto where is the rod?